# Why does my useEffect run multiple times even when that component should only be rendered once?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

My useEffect is running multiple times per load even when the useEffect dependency isn't being updated. *See console.log("filtering events")*. Every time the page is loaded the useEffect runs three times (my best guess is because the components are being rendered three times?).

What I am trying to do is every time the `filters` state variable is updated I want the `filteredEvents` variable to be updated from the filters applied to all of the events and then the calendar component to be re-rendered with the new events.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import { Calendar as BigCalendar, momentLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';
import loadingIMG from "../../../assets/images/courses/signup/minionsLoading.gif"
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css"
import {
    Accordion,
    AccordionItem,
    AccordionItemHeading,
    AccordionItemPanel,
    AccordionItemButton
} from 'react-accessible-accordion'
import { navigate, Link } from 'gatsby';

moment.locale('en-US')
const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)

const CourseSignup = ({className}) => {
    const [loading, isLoading] = useState(true)

    const [allEvents, setAllEvents] = useState({
        count: undefined,
        events: undefined
    })

    useEffect(async () => {
        console.log("fetching events")
        await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/timeslots", { 
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X-API-Key': '*F-JaNdRgUkXp2s5v8x/A?D(G+KbPeSh',
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((results) => {
            let temp = []
            // Get all events
            for (var i = 0; i < results.events.length; i++) {
                // TODO: Check if class is virtual or in-person
                // TODO: Check if class is group or 1 on 1
                // TODO: get teacher name
                // TODO: get class name

                // Get all neccesary information and push to an array
                temp.push({
                    title: String(results.events[i].summary),
                    info: {
                        format: undefined,
                        type: undefined,
                        name: undefined,
                        teacher: undefined
                    },
                    description: String(results.events[i].description) || undefined,
                    start: new Date(results.events[i].start.date || results.events[i].start.dateTime),
                    end: new Date(results.events[i].end.date || results.events[i].end.dateTime),
                    url: String(results.events[i].htmlLink),
                    id: String(results.events[i].id),
                    est_locale_timecodes: {
                        start: results.events[i].start.date || results.events[i].start.dateTime,
                        end: results.events[i].end.date || results.events[i].end.dateTime
                    }
                })
            }
            // update state variable with events
            setAllEvents({
                'count': temp.length,
                'events': temp
            })
        })
        .catch(() => {
            // incase of an error replace all events
            setAllEvents({
                'count': undefined,
                'events': undefined
            })
        })
        .then(() => isLoading(false))
    }, [])


    const UserInterface = () => {
        const [filters, updateFilters] = useState({
            classTeacher: 'undefined', // name of the teacher (default: undefined)
            classType: undefined, // 'group', '1 on 1'
            classFormat: undefined, // 'virtual', 'in-person'
            class: className // name of class (default: undefined)
        })
        const [filteredEvents, setFilteredEvents] = useState({
            count: undefined,
            events: undefined
        })

        useEffect(() => {
            console.log("filtering events")
            if(!Object.values(filters).every(filterValue => filterValue == undefined)) {
                // let filtered = Array(allEvents.events).filter(event => {
                //     if(event.info.format == undefined || String(event.info.format).includes(filters.classFormat == undefined ? "" : filters.classFormat)) return true
                //     if(event.info.type == undefined || String(event.info.type).includes(filters.classType == undefined ? "" : filters.classType)) return true
                //     if(event.info.name == undefined || String(event.info.name).includes(filters.class == undefined ? "" : filters.class)) return true
                //     if(event.info.teacher == undefined || String(event.info.teacher).includes(filters.classTeacher == undefined ? "" : filters.classTeacher)) return true
                //     return false
                // })

                setFilteredEvents(allEvents)
            } else {
                setFilteredEvents(allEvents)
            }
        }, [filters])

        const FilterOptions = () => {
            return null
        }

        const Calendar = () => {
            const getDate = () => {
                var d = new Date()
                return (`${d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })}, ${d.getFullYear()}`)
            }

            return (
                <div id="calendar-content">
                    <div className="section-title" style={{"marginBottom":"10px"}}>
                        <h3 style={{fontFamily: "inherit"}}>{getDate()}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <BigCalendar 
                        localizer={localizer}
                        events={filteredEvents.events} 
                        startAccessor="start" 
                        endAccessor="end" 
                        style={{ height: 800 }} 
                        views={{month: true}} 
                        popup={true}
                        toolbar={false}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }

        const SignupForm = () => {
            return null
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <FilterOptions/>
                <div>
                    {loading
                        ? null
                        : <Calendar/>
                    }
                </div>
                <SignupForm/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <UserInterface/>
    )

}

export default CourseSignup
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wrapping your App Component with StrictMode Component inside index.js, if yes? then remove it and you will get the expected results and also the component is only rendered-once

And one more thing you're doing wrong which is not considered a good practice is, not to declare the callback function as async like this =>

```
useEffect(async() => {}, [])
```

Because if you will do that, then if you want to return a cleanup function from inside useEffect the next time it runs, you won't be to do so

For example, let's say you have a search engine which is tied to the backend through useEffect, now on every input change the useEffect will be triggered

```
useEffect(() => {} , [onEveryInputChange])
```

Now every time useEffect is gonna run a timeout will be registered and a request will be sent to the backend once the time expires

```
useEffect(() => {
    const myTimeout = setTimeout(() => fetch('someUrl').then().catch(), [2000])
}, [onEveryInputChange])
```

Now you don't want to send req for every input, and you only want to send a req once you are done typing or once you have taken a pause of 2 secs after writing down a few words, so in that case, we use cleanup function

```
useEffect(() => {
      const myTimeout = setTimeout(() => fetch('someUrl').then().catch(), [2000])
    
    return () => clearTimeout(myTimeout) // This is a cleanup function
}, [onEveryInputChange])
```

So the next time you enter something within 2 sec the cleanup will run first
and will prevent the req from getting executed

Comment: I don't have anything wrapped with StrictMode and I will look into changing from async useEffect

Comment: Did you checked it, cause when we create an app using npx create-react-app, it automatically wraps the app component with strict mode component

Comment: Yeah, my top level is just a RecoilRoot

Comment: It's a React 18 "feature". Also see https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-18-the-trickiness-of-useeffect-fadfa65fa4b4

Comment: I'm using react 17